# How to calculate $\int_{C}{}\frac{\bar{z}}{z+i} dz$ if $C$ is a circle: $|z+i|=3$?

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, complex-numbers, circles, contour-integration

The task:
$$
\text{Calculate } \int_{C}{}f(z)dz\text{, where } f(z)=\frac{\bar{z}}{z+i}\text{, and } C \text{ is a circle } |z+i|=3\text{.}
$$
Finding the circle's center and radius:
$$
|z+i|=|x+yi+i|=|x+(y+1)i|=3
\\
x^2+(y+1)^2=3^2
$$
Parametrizing the circle:
$$
z(t)=i+3e^{-2\pi i t}
$$

Now I need to calculate this integral:
$$
\int_{0}^{1}{f(z(t))z'(t)dt}=
2\pi\int_{0}^{1}{
\frac{1-3ie^{-2\pi i t}}{e^{4 \pi i t}}dt
}
$$

Unfortunately I calculated this integral, and it's equal to $0$. Is this correct? I don't think so. Where did I go wrong? Maybe I made a mistake when calculating the integral - what would be the best way to calculate it?

Comment: Hi! It's been a while. I hope you're staying safe and healthy during the pandemic. I've reached out to contact you a few times, but am unsure whether you've received the notes? If you would, please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. And feel free to up vote an answer as you see fit. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that
$$
\frac{\overline{z}}{z+i}
=\frac{\overline{z}\cdot \overline{(z+i)}}{(z+i)\cdot \overline{(z+i)}}
=\frac{\overline{z}\cdot \overline{(z+i)}}{|z+i|^2}
=\frac{1}{9}\cdot \overline{z}\cdot \overline{(z+i)}
$$

Your parametrization of the path should be
$$
z(t)=\color{red}{-i}+3e^{2\pi i t},\quad [0,1]
$$

If your integral is $I$, then
\begin{align}
9I
&=\int_C \overline{z}\cdot \overline{(z+i)}\,dz\\
&=\int_0^1 (i+3e^{-2\pi i t})\cdot 3e^{-2\pi i t}\cdot 6\pi i\cdot  e^{2\pi it}
\,dt\\
&=\int_0^1 (i+3e^{-2\pi i t})\cdot 18\pi i\,dt=-18\pi
\end{align}

and thus $I=-2\pi$.

Comment: I have a different presentation from yours and I explicitly pointed out a (crucial) mistake in OP's answer. Also, I have a different order of details and the calculations are straightforward, which is close to the definition of complex integral via parametrization.// My answer is accepted does not mean that yours is inferior. (-:

Answer (score 2):

Note that on the circle $C$, given by $|z+i|=3$, we have $\overline{z+i}=\frac9{z+i}$.  Hence, on $C$

$$f(z)=\frac9{(z+i)^2}+i\frac{1}{z+i}$$

Then,

$$\begin{align}
\oint_{|z+i|=3}\frac{\overline{z}}{z+i}\,dz&=\color{red}{\oint_{|z+i|=3}\frac{9}{(z+i)^2}\,dz}+\color{blue}{i\oint_{|z+i|=3}\frac{1}{z+i}\,dz}\\\\
&=\color{red}{0}\color{blue}{-2\pi}
\end{align}$$

---

---

As an alternative approach, we will evaluate the integral using parameterization.  On $C$, $z=-i+3e^{i\theta}$ where $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$.  Furthermore, on $C$C we have $f(z)=\frac{\bar z}{z+i}=\frac{i+3e^{-i\theta}}{3e^{i\theta}}$ and $dz=i3e^{i\theta}\,d\theta$.  Hence,

$$\begin{align}
\oint_C f(z)\,dz&=\int_0^{2\pi} \left(-1+i3e^{-i\theta}\right)\,d\theta\\\\
&=-2\pi
\end{align}$$

as expected!

Comment: How did you calculate $\overline{z+i}$ to be $\frac{9}{z+i}$? $$$$ Also, another user gave the answer to the integral and according to them it's $0$: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3988202/750244 $\\$ Could you verify which is correct? Thank you.

Comment: First, $|z+i|=3$.  This implies that $|z+i|^2=9$.  And we know that $9=|z+i|^2=(z+i)(\overline{z+i}\overline{z+i})$.  Now, simply divide. As far as the analysis herein, it is correct.  I'll edit to add another approach to reinforce the validity.

Comment: @bosendorfer Hi! It's been a while. I hope you're staying safe and healthy during the pandemic. I've reached out to contact you a few times, but am unsure whether you've received the notes? If you would, please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can. And feel free to up vote an answer as you see fit. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly use the Residue Theorem in this case since $\frac{\overline{z}}{z+i}$ is not holomorphic, so your approach is entirely reasonable. Your calculation of the integral is correct since

$$\int_{0}^{1}e^{2k\pi ti}dt=\left.\frac{1}{2\pi ki}e^{2k\pi kti}\right|_0^{1}=\frac{1}{2\pi ki}(1-1)=0$$

for any integer $k$, and so

\begin{align*}
2\pi\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1-3ie^{-2\pi it}}{e^{4\pi i t}}dt&=2\pi\int_{0}^{1}e^{-4\pi i t}dt-6\pi i\int_{0}^{1}e^{-6\pi it}dt\\
&=2\pi(0)-6\pi i(0)\\
&=0
\end{align*}

Comment: Another user gave the answer to this integral and according to them it's $0-2\pi$: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3988349/750244 $$$$ Could you verify which is correct? Thank you.

Comment: @bosendorfer: "Your calculation of the integral is correct". OP's parameterization of the path is incorrect.